# Asp.net session not showing

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

I am storing primary key value of gridview row in session and showing it on another webpage I am trying below code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Migrate")
    {
        int _rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow _selectedrow = GridView1.Rows[_rowindex];
        TableCell _firstcell = _selectedrow.Cells[0];
        Session["authId"] = _firstcell.Text + "";

        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
}
```

Normally code works fine but `_firstcell` value not storing in session after redirecting my page to webform2 it running else condition. I am using below code onpageload of webform2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["authId"].ToString()))
        Response.Write(Session["authId"].ToString());
    else
    { 
        Response.Write("Empty Session");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your gridview rowcommand and check value of  _firstcell.Text. Does it have a value ?

Comment: Have you tried to set another session variable on one page, and read it on another page? so you could verify if it is a general or specific problem.

Comment: Yes I put breakpoint and it show me there is no value show in _firstcell variable so I do further work on my code and get primary key of gridview row. I post below my own answer where I changed one line of code to get my desire answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing below code:

```
int _rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow _selectedrow = GridView1.Rows[_rowindex];
TableCell _firstcell = _selectedrow.Cells[0];
Session["authId"] = _firstcell.Text + "";
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
```

into below code:

```
int _rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
//we used datakey here for get primary key of specific row
var id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[_rowindex].Value);
Session["authId"] = id;
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
```

I got my solution.